# glreadpixels is slower than x11 based screenshot

Tags: linux, opengl, ffmpeg

I am working on an opengl based simulation application, in which I need to make multiple screenshots in a second. I have tried 2 ways of doing it in my application.
1) use glreadpixels
2) use x11 based screenshot. ex:  ffmpeg -f x11grab -s 1024x768 -i :0.0  output.png

I found that second solution is about 3 times faster than first one. I have expected the first solution to be faster. But in practice it is slower. I am curious why glreadpixels is slower?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`glReadPixels (...)` is a synchronous round-trip operation (when it is not used with a Pixel Buffer Object). You send it to GL, it has to finish all of the commands it has buffered up to that point and ***then*** it returns the result of that operation.

On the other hand, if you use a method defined by a window system to grab the contents of a window, the window system is free to implement the operation a number of different ways. Often you will get a copy of the last thing the window system actually presented, which may be 1 or more frames older than what you would get if you called `glReadPixels (...)` and waited for GL to finish drawing.